# error message "source: Is a directory" in lftp mirror

Tags: rsync, lftp

I am on machine A as user A1, password P1, and have a folder L1. I want to keep it synchronized with a folder L2 for user A2 (P1) on a remote machine B. I know rsync cannot work over ftp, and I installed lftp on A.

I wrote a script on machine A(I cannot put any script on machine B)

```
REMOTEHOST='B'   #this is machine from which I want files
REMOTEUSER='A2'   #this is user for the machine
REMOTEPASSWORD='P2' #this is password for user of remote machine

#lftp
lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
mirror L2 L1"
```

The files are copied, but I get a message "source: Is a directory"

I tried -R flag and adding a / at end of L1 and L2, but didnt work.
How can I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 1):

So I just ran into this. You should try using **mget** instead which is a command to lftp allowing the downloading of individual files...kinda lame that mirror can't handle this but the concept of "mirror" is supposed to represent mirroring a directory which I suppose makes sense.

An example based on what you have would be:

```
#lftp
lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
mget L2 L1"
```

You can also do a oneliner like so:

```
lftp -u user,pass -e "mget /home/user/coolfile.txt /mnt/raid/; quit" sftp://server.net
```

One thing to remember with mget is that you loose the parallel and segmented downloading options so speeds may be slower.

More on [this](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) excellent lftp man page.

Comment: Hm - but the question was to mirror a directory, there's no word about individual files, is it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the correct way to do that is to use the `-c` cli option instead of `-f`